# Horizontal Page Indicator in a ViewPager

Tags: android, user-interface, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager and I want to use the "horizontal page indicator" (see pic below) to make it clear the user can scroll horizontally. Although I see it used in many apps I can't find much info on it. I was hoping it would be as simple as an enableX method in the ViewPager or Adapter but it doesn't seem to be the case. Can anybody tell me if there is a way to enable this on the ViewPager or is this implemented as an image on all apps that use it? Also, what is the name of this type of page indicator?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Android-ViewPagerIndicator library by Jake Wharton
https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

Comment: Works a treat. Thanks buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jake Wharton's [Android-ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator).

[image]

This is combination of android's `ViewPager` and a set of different indicators as you can see in the image above.